Why is there such a big difference in gpu read and write bandwidth between iOS and Android
In the mobile games I developed with unity, there was a strange phenomenon: the Android read/write bandwidth was around 400mb/s to 500mb/s, but the ios read/write bandwidth was around 3gb/s. The data is shown in the figure below.
I wonder if this data is reasonable? Perhaps the difference between hardware architectures is causing such a big difference in gpu bandwidth between ios and Android, or is there something wrong with my statistics that is causing this problem?
If you can tell me the answer, or give me guidance, I would be very grateful.
                                                                  Best wishes.




Android and ios data are obtained by perfdog performance testing tool
memoryless has been enabled for depth buffer and stencil buffer on ios. Moreover, the frame capture analysis on xcode shows that the depth buffer and stencil buffer are already memoryless. Only the color buffer has a load action and a store action. The total read/write bandwidth is also displayed on xcode at around 3gb/s.
The Android test model is PGT-AN10 Honor Magic5 Pro. To further verify the correctness of the Android data, I also ran a round of tests on the snapDragon profiler. The data displayed by snapDragon is consistent with that of perfdog, with read/write bandwidths ranging from 400mb/s to 500mb/s.

